# how to had more 50000 urls in django sitemap

Tags: python, django, sitemap

```
path(
    'sitemap.xml',
    sitemap, {
        'sitemaps': sitemaps
        }, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'
),
```

this above example is my sitemap config in Project level `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap

from .models import Post

class PostSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'always'
    priority = 0.9
    protocol = 'https'
    limit = 5

    def items(self):
        return Post.aupm.all()
    
    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.updated
```

this above code is for `sitemaps.py` in application level
which generating this code

```
<urlset>
<url>
<loc>
https://localhost:8000/en/kavi/lobaan-ke-5-laabh-aur-upyog-aur-7-mithk-0x76/
</loc>
<lastmod>2022-01-28</lastmod>
<changefreq>always</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
```

What I want is :

1. what to do if i have much more element in more than 50,000 (fifty thousand) element in that application,
2. If i want to add more element(ie sitemap) from diffrent application

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible using [sitemap indexes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/76418206/difference-between-sitemaps-and-sitemaps-index?hl=en). From docs:

> The sitemap framework also has the ability to create a sitemap index that references individual sitemap files, one per each section defined in your `sitemaps` dictionary. The only differences in usage are:
>
> - You use two views in your `URLconf`: `django.contrib.sitemaps.views.index()` and `django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap()`.
> - The `django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap()` view should take a section keyword argument.

See more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index).